# Python: Fitting images inside A4 PDF

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, printing, pyfpdf

I have some images that i want to convert to pdf. currently i'm using this code with FPDF:

```py
def image_to_pdf(image_url, pdf_url):
    from fpdf import FPDF
    pdf_model = FPDF()
    pdf_model.add_page()
    pdf_model.image(image_url, 0, 0)
    pdf_model.output(pdf_url)
    return pdf_url
```

This code is putting the image directly inside PDF which may cause some problems. One of them is that if the image is bigger than  the A4 paper, it would get out of paper and some parts of it would not be printed.

I'm also ok with using pillow but i don't know how to use it.

Comment: I suggest to consider package [PyMuPDF](https://pypi.org/project/PyMuPDF/). Inserting images (and other stuff) is super-simple. Just specify a rectangle inside one of the PDF's pages, or add the image file as its own PDF page to your PDF. In any case, the image is appropriately scaled to fit. Please ping me if interested.

Comment: @JorjMcKie I tried to use it, but the [code in the docs](https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/recipes-images.html#how-to-make-one-pdf-of-all-your-pictures-or-files) makes a pdf with the size of my image and i don't want that. i want the pdf page to be A4. how can i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
import fitz  # PyMuPDF

images =[...]  # list of image file names
doc= fitz.open()  # new, empty PDF
for image in images:  # read image file names
    page = doc.new_page()  # makes a new empty A4 page: (width=595, height=842)
    page.insert_image(page.rect, filename=image)
doc.ez_save("output.pdf")
```

Above puts every image on its own A4 page - scaled to the maximum possible extent and centered - meaning image center and page center are the same.

Comment: Is the default page size of A4 specific to this package or is it a universal PDF property?

Comment: I am the original creator of the package. As I am German, the decision was easy to choose a default paper format that makes sense because it fits into the international metric system. But you can choose any other format too. And their is a set of over 1 dozen of predefined standard paper formats, including Ltter.

Comment: I hope it didn't sound like I was complaining, A4 is a perfectly sensible default.  I was just curious.  As a US citizen I wish we would adopt the A system too, but I don't think I'll see it in my lifetime.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/5987/mark-ransom no worries . Its just amazing that the most advanced country is incapable of putting away with all those medieval units for lengths, areas, volumes, weights and what not else. The US scientist of course know what is reasonable and use what makes sense ...

Comment: Not always: https://www.simscale.com/blog/nasa-mars-climate-orbiter-metric/

Comment: I knew about that one before - but tried to be polite.

Comment: @JorjMcKie Your answer was prefect and it worked correctly, alsod using your package made my program better by supporting more image file types. but can i know why the name of the python package is "fitz" and not something like "pymupdf"?

Comment: Thank you https://stackoverflow.com/users/10802527/k-j for helping with this explanation! As the original creator of the package, I am afraid this was my fault . But we are currently "rebasing" PyMuPDF internally, which as the side-effect that (1) the import name can be changed, and (2) the top-level name "fitz" will disappear medium term.